# Adding Legends in Pandas Plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am plotting Density Graphs using Pandas Plot. But I am not able to add appropriate legends for each of the graphs. My code and result is as as below:-

```
for i in tickers:
    df = pd.DataFrame(dic_2[i])
    mean=np.average(dic_2[i])
    std=np.std(dic_2[i])
    maximum=np.max(dic_2[i])
    minimum=np.min(dic_2[i])
    df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=mean,scale=std,size=len(dic_2[i])))
    ax=df.plot(kind='density', title='Returns Density Plot for '+ str(i),colormap='Reds_r')
    df1.plot(ax=ax,kind='density',colormap='Blues_r')
```

[image]

You can see in the pic, top right side box, the legends are coming as 0. How do I add something meaningful over there?

```
print(df.head())
           0
0  -0.019043
1 -0.0212065
2  0.0060413
3  0.0229895
4 -0.0189266
```

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: @AndrewL - df only has daily returns data for an Index. I am editing above with a df.head()

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want to restructure the way you've created the graph. An easy way to do this is to create the `ax` before plotting:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['returns_a'] = [x for x in np.random.randn(100)]
df['returns_b'] = [x for x in np.random.randn(100)]
print(df.head())
   returns_a  returns_b
0   1.110042  -0.111122
1  -0.045298  -0.140299
2  -0.394844   1.011648
3   0.296254  -0.027588
4   0.603935   1.382290

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

I then created the dataframe using the parameters specified in your variables:

```
mean=np.average(df.returns_a)
std=np.std(df.returns_a)
maximum=np.max(df.returns_a)
minimum=np.min(df.returns_a)

pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=mean,scale=std,size=len(df.returns_a))).rename(columns={0: 'std_normal'}).plot(kind='density',colormap='Blues_r', ax=ax)
df.plot('returns_a', kind='density', ax=ax)
```

This second dataframe you're working with is created by default with column `0`. You'll need to rename this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a simpler way to do this. Just add column names to the dataframes.

```
for i in tickers:
    df = pd.DataFrame(dic_2[i],columns=['Empirical PDF'])
    print(df.head())
    mean=np.average(dic_2[i])
    std=np.std(dic_2[i])
    maximum=np.max(dic_2[i])
    minimum=np.min(dic_2[i])
    df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=mean,scale=std,size=len(dic_2[i])),columns=['Normal PDF'])
    ax=df.plot(kind='density', title='Returns Density Plot for '+ str(i),colormap='Reds_r')
    df1.plot(ax=ax,kind='density',colormap='Blues_r')
```

[image]