# Plotting Legend On Pandas Plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have the current dataframe:

[image]

I have used the pandas inbuilt plot to kind of plot the different regions on 1 graph against each other and got the following result:

```
plotting_df = df_grouped[[*type_list]]
plotting_df = plotting_df.reset_index()
plotting_df.plot(x='year', y='all_motor_vehicles', kind = 'scatter', legend = True)
```

[image]

I just wanted to know how I could make it so the things that are plotted are labelled with the legends they correspond to in region_name and was wondering how I could get it as a continuous line as using 'line' as the kind just gives me vertical lines. Cheers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Legends in Pandas Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225806/adding-legends-in-pandas-plot)

Comment: [This question has been asked before. Take a look at this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225806/adding-legends-in-pandas-plot)

Comment: I don't see how that helps in my specific case. Each data point has an assigned region name and I want the datapoints of the same region names to be linked with a line and then labelled with a legend. I don't want to have to create new columns with each of the datapoints of region names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `region_name` A, B, C, D as example

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iterables = [[2000, 2019], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['year', 'region_name'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'all_motor_vehicles': range(1, 9), 'pedal_cycles': range(1, 9)}, index=index)

unstacked = df.unstack(level=1)

unstacked.plot(y='all_motor_vehicles')

plt.gca().set_xticks(unstacked.index.values)
plt.gca().set_ylabel("all_motor_vehicles")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This makes more sense than the previous. I was wondering, how would I make it so each is a line graph. Insead of there being blue bars I just have a continuous line for region A across all 19 years and a continuous line for B etc etc?

Comment: So I tried implementing it this way, however, when I try inputting my dataframe in, it's requiring a list like object instead of a dataframe?

Comment: @Nhyi What's the output of your `print(unstacked.index.values)`?

Comment: the error is happening in the index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['year', 'region_name']). Instead I put my dataframe in place of iterables

Comment: @Nhyi I just use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()` to give some sample data. You only just need to use your dataframe.

Comment: So it's stating that there is no numeric data to plot. I have double checked and all of the columns are numbers and not objects

Comment: @Nhyi Let's discuss in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230989